# How can I get a full dict when I have performed a Many-to-one relationships?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, python-3.6

```
class EbConfig(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specific_field_config_id = models.IntegerField()
    judge_result = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class EbResult(models.Model):
    eb_config = models.ForeignKey(EbConfig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cc_log_info_base_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    eb_config_id = models.IntegerField()

result = EbResult.objects.filter(...)...
```

After satisfying my condition, I got a QuerySet named "result". 
When I input:

```
result.select_related('eb_config').values()
```

I get something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'eb_config_id': 1, 'cc_log_info_base_id': 10001},...>
```

But what I want to get is like this:

```
"<QuerySet [{'eb_config_id': 1, 'cc_log_info_base_id': 10001, 'id ':'', 'specific_field_config_id ':'', 'judge_result ':''},...>"
```

What can I do to get that?
I knew, I can get an object of EbConfig by:

```
list(test)[0].eb_config
```

But what I truely want is a full dict of EbConfig INNER JOIN EbResult.
When I print `result.query`, I find a right SQL sentence which can successfully run in MySQL and get a result I expect.

Comment: What if the two models have *overlapping* field names?

Comment: I think it does not matter.And I checked, it does not have any overlapping field name.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong approach. To take full advantage of Django, you should use model instances as much as possible; `values()` is for specialised use-cases only. Don't use it, and follow the relationships in your template or wherever.

Comment: Thanks for pointing!! And How do you usually turn a model instance into a corresponding JSON?

Comment: @edcSam: with a serializer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/ (there is good support for XML, JSON en YML, although one can write their own serializer as well, if they want to)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman@Willem Van Onsem:Thanks very much!! I have completed this part through serializer. And there are lots of codes waiting for me to be refactored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soft ForeignKey and serializer.

You can totally perform it in Django.

[serializer doc recommend by Willem Van Onsem in question comment](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization)

[How can I perform ManyToOne without ForeignKey in db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849051/how-can-i-perform-manytoone-without-foreignkey-in-db)