# How can I perform ManyToOne without ForeignKey in db?

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models

```
eb_config_object = models.ForeignKey(EbConfig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to serialize an object, which includes another object. But the problem is in my design concept I can not allow ForeignKey(Hard foreign key) exist in my database(MySQL).

Is there any method to perform that in Django2.x?

Comment: Keep that foreign key column with allow null option.

Comment: what exactly you want to do? Why you can't allow foreignkey?

Comment: @seuling I just want to get all the benifits from ForeignKey but not generate any physical ForeignKey in my database. Because I want to avoid the affect by it, which may be restrictive, high maintenance cost, unfriendly to fisher. It is just my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eb_config_object = models.ForeignKey(EbConfig, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)
```

When I post this question, I had known the attributes(db_constraint) of ForeignKey.But I failed to get through the SQL automatic generated by Django. It tells me can not find a  field.

Just migrate your models to physical database by manage.py, and all works.You can get all the benifits from ForeignKey which is given by Django, and there is no any physical ForeignKey in your database.